# Google sheets, get range of rows, where column intersect cell is empty

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Basically I want to use an auto-sorting script through the script editor in Google sheets, but I want it to smartly pick a range of rows, by only selecting those rows where a specific column has an empty cell.

All other rows that have that column's cell populated would stay put.  Here is the sort code I've found.

```
 /**
 * Automatically sorts the 1st column (not the header row) Ascending.
 */
function onEdit(event){
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 1;
  var tableRange = "A2:T99"; // What to sort.

  if(editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy){   
    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    range.sort( { column : columnToSortBy, ascending: true } );
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: this will only sort the values in the cells (metadata such as formats, notes etc will not be sorted, as they would with the GAS range.sort() method).

```
function onEdit(event)
{
  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var editedCell = sheet.getActiveCell();

  var columnToSortBy = 0; // zero-based index

  if (editedCell.getColumn() == columnToSortBy)
  {
    var columnToWatch = 5; // checking this column for blank cells (zero-based index)
    var tableRange = "A2:T99"; // what to sort

    var range = sheet.getRange(tableRange);
    var data = range.getValues();
    var dataCopy = data.slice();
    dataCopy.sort(function(a, b) {return a[columnToSortBy] > b[columnToSortBy] ? 1 : (a[columnToSortBy] < b[columnToSortBy] ? -1 : 0);});
    var j = -1;
    for (var i = 0, length = data.length; i < length; i++)
    {
      if (data[i][columnToWatch].toString().length)
      {
        do j++; while (!dataCopy[j][columnToWatch].toString().length);
        data[i] = dataCopy[j];
      }
    }
    range.setValues(data);  
  }
}
```

Comment: So there's no way to use range.sort where the range simply excludes certain rows, or puts them at the bottom?  If not, this will still work as I don't use notes, and the formatting is the same between cells of the same column.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use the range.sort() method to do as you require.